# SSH connection gets lost, but not when logged in to MySQL

Tags: ssh, openssh

When I open an SSH connection to our database server and leave it open for a longer time, the connection gets lost at some point. I don't know why or how, but this happens a lot. I still see the prompt, but can't enter anything. I usually kill the terminal and open a new one. If I wait much longer, I get an error message.

However, when I login to MySQL after logging in with SSH, this doesn't happen. The connection stays open. If this is possible, I guess it's a matter of keeping the connection alive.

**How does this work and can I set SSH to do better?**

Comment: Have you tried setting the `ServerAliveInterval` client-side ssh option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement `ServerAliveInterval`, `ClientAliveInterval`, and `ClientAliveCountMax` to solve your timeout issue.

[Please see this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3027/10805)