# How do I prevent just 'exit' from being saved when I close an SSH connection?

Tags: bash, ssh, command-history, ssh-tunneling

When searching for a way to do this on Google, all I can find are ways to quit the session without saving history (like `kill -9 $$`), but I have the opposite problem. I want to save all of my history, just not the `exit` command.

Comcast has really abused us at work such that our SSH tunnels can't stay up for more than 5 minutes without getting broken pipe. After reconnecting, I go to run the last command and sure enough, I forget it's now `exit`!

Comment: If you keep losing your connection, GNU `screen` would be a good idea. It will allow you to get back into your previous session with everything intact.

Comment: @drewbenn His problem is that it's not saving everything else in the history file. How will filtering out exit make it save the other stuff?

Comment: For your comcast problem, try adding `ServerAliveInterval 30`to your `~/.ssh/config`, they may be killing idle connections.

Comment: Right now it's at 60 @StéphaneChazelas, I'll try decreasing it.

Comment: Really it's just a build server, so before I would just log in, run the build, keep it open all day, and then let the pipe break when my computer goes to sleep. To deal with Comcast, I enclosed my pipe in a script that automatically restarts and logs broken pipes (we were going to present this information to Comcast, until we found out they don't care), so I have to manually `exit` at the end of the day otherwise it would log the entire night as downtime.

Comment: Use ctrl-D instead of exit to terminate your session.

Comment: Adding `HISTIGNORE=exit` does seem to be working for me. But `CTRL+D` works great! It would be nice to get `HISTIGNORE` working through.

Comment: This might sound dumb @wurtel, but want to post that as an answer? I don't know how I didn't know about CTRL+D until now.

Comment: @NobleUplift done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell will read commands from your terminal (i.e. the shell's standard input) until it's told to stop (by entering the `exit` command) or when an end-of-file (EOF) is encountered (just like when the shell is executing a script).

If you enter the `exit` command, this will first be saved into the history, and then the shell will quit. Entering <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> generates an EOF; as this is not a command but an input state, it can't be saved in the shell's history.

Note that you can instruct `bash` to ignore EOF; this can be done in 2 ways:

- set -o ignoreeof
- IGNOREEOF=`n`

The first way is equivalent to doing `IGNOREEOF=10`, meaning you have to hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> 10 times in a row before the shell will exit. This is to prevent accidentally terminating the shell e.g. if you mistype <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> or whatever.

Note also that <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> only generates an `EOF` when entered as the first thing on a line (i.e. after an enter), `bash` ignores it if anything has already been typed on the line.

The <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> also generates `EOF` outside the shell. E.g.:

```
$ wc
foo bar
<ctrl-D>
      1       2       8
```

`wc` has counted 1 line, 2 words, 8 characters (including the newline).

Here's an example with using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> after some input has been given on  the line:

```
$ wc
foo bar<ctrl-D><ctrl-D>       0       2       7
```

Now `wc` has counted zero lines (no `enter` had been given), 2 words and 7 characters. Two <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> sequences were necessary because data had already been given; note that `bash` handles this specially (ignoring the `EOF` if something has already been entered on the line), whereas e.g. `dash` doesn't. This is probably due to the line editing facility in `bash`.

Comment: I set `IGNOREEOF=10` but it still disconnects right away on the first time

Answer (score 1):

If @StéphaneChazelas's suggestion of increasing [`ServerAliveInterval`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3026/what-do-the-options-serveraliveinterval-and-clientaliveinterval-in-sshd-conf) doesn't work (maybe try a value of `300`), then you might want to consider something like GNU `screen` or `tmux` so you can resume your dropped connections.

I have this near the top of my `~/.bashrc` on all of my remote systems:

```
screen -r >/dev/null 2>&1
```

This will do nothing if you lack a disconnected screen session (e.g. if it's your second connection, or if you just rebooted), but if you do have a screen session (that is not attached elsewhere), it will automatically reattach you.  Bam, all of your previous history (and active commands, etc.) are restored.  (This assumes you launch `screen` on your first login.)

I also couple this with a looped SSH connection.  Here's a simple version to illustrate what I'm talking about:

```
while sleep 1; do ssh remotehost; done
```

This way, when you are disconnected, you'll automatically reconnect (this is even transparent, assuming you have an ssh key and are using `ssh-agent` or a passwordless key).

Comment: I passed your answer off to my coworker who has started using screen to overcome this issue.