# sshfs "Connection reset by peer" with identify file

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-ec2, sshfs

Time to time I need create servers network - link servers and quickly copy data.

I'm using for that [SSH Filesystem (SSHFS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS) because it is simple and easy to use like connect with [Secure Shell (SSH)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell).

For better security reasons I using authentication files instead of passwords. Another reasons is that is the default setting for "[Amazon Web Services (AWS) EC2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Elastic_Compute_Cloud)".

Time to time I don't figure out where is problem with connection

```
sshfs {{user_name}}@{{server_ip}}:{{remote_path}} {{local_path}} -o "IdentityFile={{identity_path}}"
```

and I get just simple message on client

```
read: Connection reset by peer
```

and simple message on server

```
"Connection reset by peer"
```

Q what I can do next?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There can be many mistakes in syntax, and many more in connection.

Best solution is turn on verbose mode with switch

```
-o debug
```

and in my case I see problem with "absolute path to identity file"

```
no such identity: {{identity_file}}: No such file or directory
Permission denied (publickey).
read: Connection reset by peer
```

so my full command looks like this

```
sshfs {{user_name}}@{{server_ip}}:/ /mnt/{{server_ip}} -o "IdentityFile={{absolute_path}},port={{port_number}}" -o debug
```

Comment: `-o debug` is very helpful to me to find errors.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a timeout problem. Such a message ("read: Connection reset by peer") indicates that the connection was successful (the `ssh` command is OK) but ended abruptly: ssh client sent something and in return, it received a RST TCP frame which means "don't send anything, the channel is closed".

This is mainly due to a firewall disconnecting you for inactivity (but this may have other causes, like too much connections in a small timespan; firewalls are touchy these days).

To avoid timeout problems, use the `ssh` options `TCPKeepAlive` or `ServerAliveInterval`/`ServerAliveCountMax`. See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3026/203203).