# OpenSSH: What is the interval for TCPKeepAlive option?

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, tcp

In sshd config you can specify the option `TCPKeepAlive yes`. These Pakets are not encrypted so the could be spoofed. 
With the options

```
ClientAliveInterval
ClientAliveCountMax
ServerAliveInterval
ServerAliveCountMax
```

you can specify the interval of the keep alive packets and the timeout (*CountMax) after which the connection is dropped. See also here [What options `ServerAliveInterval` and `ClientAliveInterval` in sshd_config exactly do?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3026/what-options-serveraliveinterval-and-clientaliveinterval-in-sshd-config-exac/327653#327653)

With `TCPKeepAlive` you can only enable it.
So what is the interval for the TCP-Pakets beeing sent? 
After how many unsuccessful packets the connection is regarded broken and closed? Since default values are:

```
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
```

As far as I understand: The detection and closing of broken/inactive connections solely depends on the TCPKeepAlive option in the default configuration. So it is quite important to know that values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why OpenSSH doesn't offer any tweaks for `TCPKeepAlive` (which is implemented by the OS) is probably because there's no portable way to change its parameters; the only portable thing is turning it on or off with `setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &on_off)`.

On Linux, you can see (and change) the default values via the `/proc` filesystem, as documented in the `tcp(7)` manpage:

```
grep -T . /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive*
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_intvl: 75
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_probes:        9
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time:  7200
```

So, it will wait 2 hours until it will consider a connection idle, and then send 9 probes at the interval of 75 seconds.

On Linux, FreeBSD and NetBSD (but not on OpenBSD) you can also change those options on a per-socket basis with
`setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_KEEP{CNT,IDLE,INTVL}, &val)`
but, as mentioned, OpenSSH doesn't do that.