# How can I use ssh to send the output of a program to another computer continuously over time until connection is closed?

Tags: ssh, io-redirection, scp

My first naive way would be writing the output (python script) into a file and send it via `scp` but given that there output is generated overtime (like inconstantly between 1s and 1 day periods) I don't think that opening a file, writing it and then sending it is the smartest way.

Is there a better way? It doesn't have to be `ssh` but something that does not require port-forwarding or UDP holepunching.

Comment: Does `myprogram | ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=300 me@remotecomputer "cat > file"` do what you want?

Comment: More details on @MarkPlotnick 's answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3026/what-options-serveraliveinterval-and-clientaliveinterval-in-sshd-config-exac)

Comment: what i would to given that it can take a long time was to write the output to a file and then use SSHFS to mount it on the local machine and monitor the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Pipes

This is not an ssh problem. Read up on shell pipe-lines. How standard-out can be piped to a 2nd processes standard-in. see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bKzonnwoR2I for an introduction.

## If you already know this then.

Consider `ssh remote-machine remote-command` to be equivalent to `local-command`. e.g. `ssh remote-machine ls` gets a directory list on the remote. `ls | less` puts a directory listing through a pager. So `ssh remote-machine ls | less` will put a remote directory list through a pager.