# Can't connect to internet in Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ubuntu, internet

I'm having trouble getting Ubuntu connected to the internet in vmware fusion. Every other Linux distro has no trouble...

`ifconfig` shows that `eth0` is up and running, has been assigned an ipv4 address (DHCP) as well as an ipv6 address. I can `ping localhost`, but nothing else. It just stalls out. I'm running vmware in NAT (as opposed to bridged) mode, which has worked fine for all other distros I've tried (Debian, BackTrack, openSuse...). I thought Ubuntu was supposed to be ridiculously easy to work with? Seems a lot of people have had this problem, but no clear answers yet.

Thanks in advance for any guidance!

Comment: This might help: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8118/8123#8123

Comment: Probably more appropriate for http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 2):

Well, my previous assumptions were wrong. I've always read that you should run Linux under NAT in vmware, but I switched to bridged mode and now everything works. My ip address in the virtual machine is now the same as my ip address on the main machine.