# CentOS 7: write failed: broken pipe when trying to reboot

Tags: centos

Commands I've tried:

```
sudo reboot
sudo systemctl reboot
```

Both commands just ask for my password for sudo then write:

> Write failed: Broken pipe

Then they close the SSH connection and I can re-login immediately.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: This was one of this WWW site's earliest questions: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2010/

Comment: Right, both of those are set to 60 and it happens.

Answer (score 1):

The reboot is happening too quickly, before the `sshd` can properly close the connection, the os is already rebooting and ending the connection without any further messages going over the wire.