# ssh to remote server is timing out during the BASH script execution

Tags: ssh

I am executing a BASH shell script (`downloadScript.sh`) on a remote server in the below way. Since the script takes more time to execute, the remote shell is getting timed out in between.

```
ssh -i aws.pem username@remoteserver "./downloadScript.sh"
```

Please let me know how can make sure that the remote shell alive till the script execution.

Error message I am receiving:

> ```
> packet_write_wait: Connection to <remoteserver> port 22: Broken pipe
> ```

Note: I don't want to modify any configuration on remote server.

How can I add `ServerAliveInterval` and `ServerAliveCountMax` to the `ssh -i aws.pem username@remoteserver "./downloadScript.sh"` command..!?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2010/126755

Comment: Related to https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3026/126755

Comment: But how can i add `ServerAliveInterval` and `ServerAliveCountMax` in the `ssh -i aws.pem username@remoteserver "./downloadScript.sh"` command..!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comment to Vlastimil, You can use -o parameter in your ssh command. Example could be

```
ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -i aws.pem username@remoteserver "./downloadScript.sh"
```